# How can I SELECT data from 1 table while using 2 tables and GROUP BY syntax?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server that are joined together .. When I want to apply `GROUP BY` syntax and SELECT from one table, it affected into second table ..

How can I `SELECT` data from 1 table while I'm using 2 tables and `GROUP BY` syntax ?

```
SELECT     
    tblProduct.fTechnicalNo, tblProduct.fName, 
    tblProduct.fDesc, tblProduct.fRegisterDate, 
    SUM(tblOrders.fCount) AS Expr1, tblOrders.fSaleDate
FROM tblProduct 
INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblProduct.fId = tblOrders.fxProductId
WHERE     
    (tblProduct.fRegisterDate >= @Since) 
    AND (tblProduct.fRegisterDate <= @To)
GROUP BY 
    tblProduct.fTechnicalNo, tblProduct.fName, 
    tblProduct.fDesc, tblProduct.fRegisterDate, 
    tblOrders.fSaleDate, tblOrders.fCount
```

I want to `SELECT` just `tblProduct` data . but `GROUP BY` syntax change the result and shows the `tblOrders` data in result . I want just `tblProduct` result and just 1 field from `tblOrders`

Answer (score 0):

Using in inline view

```
SELECT tblproduct.ftechnicalno, 
       tblproduct.fname, 
       tblproduct.fdesc, 
       tblproduct.fregisterdate 
FROM   tblproduct 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(tblorders.fcount) AS sumoffcount, 
                          tblorders.fsaledate, 
                          tblorders.fxproductid tblorders 
                   GROUP  BY tblorders.fsaledate, 
                             tblorders.fxproductid) orderdata 
         ON tblproduct.fid = orderdata.fxproductid 
WHERE  ( tblproduct.fregisterdate >= @Since ) 
       AND ( tblproduct.fregisterdate <= @To )
```

Using a [Common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

```
With orderdata  as 
(SELECT SUM(tblorders.fcount) AS sumoffcount, 
                              tblorders.fsaledate, 
                              tblorders.fxproductid tblorders 
                       GROUP  BY tblorders.fsaledate, 
                                 tblorders.fxproductid) 
   SELECT tblproduct.ftechnicalno, 
           tblproduct.fname, 
           tblproduct.fdesc, 
           tblproduct.fregisterdate 
    FROM   tblproduct 
           INNER JOIN orderdata 
             ON tblproduct.fid = orderdata.fxproductid 
    WHERE  ( tblproduct.fregisterdate >= @Since ) 
           AND ( tblproduct.fregisterdate <= @To )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a group by an aggregate...  Your query was otherwise fine..

```
SELECT     
      tblProduct.fTechnicalNo, 
      tblProduct.fName, 
      tblProduct.fDesc, 
      tblProduct.fRegisterDate, 
      tblOrders.fSaleDate,
      SUM(tblOrders.fCount) AS Expr1
   FROM
      tblProduct 
         JOIN tblOrders ON tblProduct.fId = tblOrders.fxProductId
   WHERE     
          tblProduct.fRegisterDate >= @Since
      AND tblProduct.fRegisterDate <= @To
   GROUP BY 
      tblProduct.fTechnicalNo, 
      tblProduct.fName, 
      tblProduct.fDesc, 
      tblProduct.fRegisterDate, 
      tblOrders.fSaleDate
```